# Doubt on Caratheodory's extension theorem

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

This doubt is on the Caratheodory's extension in Billingsley. The main theorem says that a countably additive probability measure $P$ on a algebra can be extended to a countability additive probability measure $P^*$ on a sigma algebra generated by the algebra. I see only finite additivity and countable sub-additivity of $P$ is used in the proofs. I may be missing something.

Answer (score 5):

Finite additivity and countable sub-additivity is equivalent to countable additivity. The proof is below.

Let $\mu$ be a measure. It is clear that if $\mu$ is countably additive then it is finitely additive and countably sub-additive.

Assume that $\mu$ is countably sub-additive and finitely additive. Consider a collection $\{A_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ of disjoint measurable sets. On one hand we have that 
$$
  \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)
$$
by countable sub-additivity.
But for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(A_n) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n\right) \leq \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right),
$$
which follows by finite additivity. Letting $N\to \infty$, we have 
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n) \leq \mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right),
$$
which gives equality.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, it was trivial, i did not notice.